The critical vulnerability related to the AWS Secret Access Key in the .env file [For OSS Maintainers: VEX Notice]
This issue includes a critical vulnerability where an AWS secret access key was exposed in the .env file.
For OSS Maintainers: VEX Notice
If you're an OSS maintainer and Trivy has detected vulnerabilities in your project that you believe are not actually exploitable, consider issuing a VEX (Vulnerability Exploitability eXchange) statement.
VEX allows you to communicate the actual status of vulnerabilities in your project, improving security transparency and reducing false positives for your users.
Learn more and start using VEX: https://aquasecurity.github.io/trivy/v0.55/docs/supply-chain/vex/repo#publishing-vex-documents
To disable this notice, set the TRIVY_DISABLE_VEX_NOTICE environment variable.
For OSS Maintainers: VEX Notice
--------------------------------
If you're an OSS maintainer and Trivy has detected vulnerabilities in your project that you believe are not actually exploitable, consider issuing a VEX (Vulnerability Exploitability eXchange) statement.
VEX allows you to communicate the actual status of vulnerabilities in your project, improving security transparency and reducing false positives for your users.
Learn more and start using VEX: https://aquasecurity.github.io/trivy/v0.55/docs/supply-chain/vex/repo#publishing-vex-documents

To disable this notice, set the TRIVY_DISABLE_VEX_NOTICE environment variable.


imageblueprint (oracle 8.5)
===========================
Total: 0 (CRITICAL: 0)


/app/.env (secrets)
===================
Total: 1 (CRITICAL: 1)

CRITICAL: AWS (aws-secret-access-key)
════════════════════════════════════════
AWS Secret Access Key
────────────────────────────────────────
 /app/.env:2 (added by 'RUN /bin/sh -c chown -R myuser:myuser /a')
────────────────────────────────────────
   1   AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
   2 [ AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=****************************************
   3   AWS_REGION=xxx-xxxx-x
────────────────────────────────────────


Is there a question here?

Solution is:
Remove Secrets from the .env File
This issue includes a critical vulnerability where an AWS secret access key was exposed in the .env file. This poses a security risk as sensitive credentials can be leaked. The key to mitigating the issue was commented out/Removed, and the recommendation is to manage secrets via environment variables or an AWS IAM role
